# Function Retornando Outra Função

Tags: javascript

Estou construindo uma calculadora (https://jsfiddle.net/rwt3am1L/). O resultado do cálculo aparece na tela quando eu clico na tecla de igual, após isso, ela dá um "reset", contudo, esse "reset" está acontecendo antes do resultado sair na tela. Tenho uma ideia do que esteja acontecendo, mas não sei como resolver.

```js
const reset = (res, calc) => {
  const cleanRes = res.textContent = "";
  const cleanCalc = calc.length = ""

  return {
     cleanCalc;
  }
};

const showResult = (res, calc) => {
  res.textContent = eval(calc.join(""));
  const { cleanCalc } = reset(res, calc);
};
```

Eu só queria chamar a função "cleanCalc" dentro de "reset", mas parece que toda função é executada, pois a caixa de resposta também é limpada através da variável "cleanRes".

Se eu fizer da seguinte maneira, funciona, mas o contrário não:

```js
const reset = (res, calc) => {
  const cleanRes = res.textContent = "";
  const cleanCalc = calc.length = ""
};

const showResult = (res, calc) => {
  res.textContent = eval(calc.join(""));
  calc.length = "";
};
```

Apenas não gostaria de repetir código. É possível fazer o que estou tentando?

Desde já, agradeço a atenção!

Comment: Acho que a sua pergunta precisa de mais detalhes. Tente a **[edit]** para acrescentar mais informações.

Comment: Eu tentei explicar de uma outra forma, acho que agora tá melhor para entender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, o seu código tinha alguns retornos não utilizados e condicionais ternários que deixam o código mais difícil de ler, então recomendo uma limpeza. Fiz um fork no seu Fiddle com algumas alterações que espero ajudem a deixar mais claro o que estou falando (https://jsfiddle.net/wzh5atye/1/).

Em relação à sua pergunta, seu `reset` estava limpando tanto a "memória" (que é o seu array `calc`) quanto o seu "display" (que é o `textContent` do seu `<span>`) e isso acontecia depois de você calcular o resultado e exibir.

Deixando bem claro: o seu `return` no final do `reset()` não estava fazendo absolutamente nada no código. A definição da constante `cleanCalc` também não.

O que eu recomendo para manter o `reset()` como um único método, é deixar o parâmetro `res` como opcional, assim vc não precisa limpar o `<span>` quando ele não é passado:

```
const reset = (res, calc) => {
  if (res) res.textContent = "";
  calc.length = 0;
};

const showResult = (res, calc) => {
  res.textContent = eval(calc.join(""));
  reset(null, calc);
};
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, deu certo. Mas queria entender por qual motivos eu não conseguia usar a função que estava retornando, sendo que, nas funções fábricas é possível fazer isso.

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira fácil seria manter a variável `res.textContent` com seu conteúdo na função `reset`. Dessa forma, só o `calc` vai ser resetado e quando a função `result` for chamada de novo o resultado apropriado vai ser atribuído à variável `res.textContent`.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que você quis dizer. Eu só queria executar uma função dentro de outra, mas parece que toda ela está sendo executada.

Answer (score -2):

Se ele estivesse saindo antes do resultado você veria o resultado, se ele limpa a tela e não aparece o resultado é porque você está chamando um método embaixo do outro. Use o método `reset` como escolha do usuário para limpar a tela como um botão ou limpe apenas quando ele digitar um outro número. Creio que você esteja começando, procure desenhar o passo a passo do seu código, use calculadoras existentes e mapeie o que elas fazem, depois aplique em seu código.

**EDIT1:**
Vi o seu código agora e é exatamente o que eu falei, o reset está limpando os resultados, se você comenta o reset ele funciona normalmente.

```js
const showResult = (res, calc) => {
    res.textContent = eval(calc.join(""));
    //reset(res, calc);
};
```

**Adendo:** de acordo com o site da mozilla (https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) o uso do eval pode ser usado para inserção de código, então evite usá-lo!